# How can I use dynamic variable on route that exists in array or something

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

So.. the idea is. The user can create projects on my website that will generate a unique id of the project (eg: `as281hjkfs92jklfasf`)

And the url should be something like `/projects/as281hjkfs92jklfasf/folder`

And If I change manually the url to something wrong like `/projects/AAAAAAA/folder` I want it to redirect the users to a error page or something.

My react route:

```
<Route path="/projects/" render={({ match: { url } }) => (
                            <Route path={`${url}/*/folder/*`} component={teste} />
                    )}
```

This work for all the urls but I want to use a variable instead of `*` or something.

Thanks.